# Python using pyodbc the process is on pending

Tags: python, pyodbc

every time I run something with pyodbc (insert, update, etc) the process rest in pending and I must kill from SQL. What I am doing wrong?

```
import sys
sys.path.append ('C:/Users/xxxxx/source/repos/xxxx/env/Lib/site-packages')
import pypyodbc
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                'Server=xxxxxxx;'
                                'Database=Testing;'
                                'uid=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxxx')
cur=connection.cursor()
qry="Update Appoggio2 set ins='Ca1' where ins='Ro1'"
cur.execute (qry)
cur.close
connection.close
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with ODBC. There is probably another process/sql job updating that table, so MSSQL puts other jobs in pending mode. Check if any queries running. Can also troubleshoot why MSSQL put your job in pending.  Also, `cur.close()`, `connection.close()`

Comment: I guess it was cur,commit() that was missed but not sure. No query or transaction running in parallel, I am running python in my DW and there was nothing more than the Python code running.

Comment: Perhaps add `connection.autocommit = True` immediately after opening the connection.

Comment: True, cur.commit() is missing. Autocommit is optional.